# Is "network" perceived as a verb?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Network for passenger route development and connect!

This is a slogan for conferences devoted to route development (airports and airlines). I feel that something is wrong with it.
1. "Network" - would native speakers perceive it as a verb? Because my first reaction that it's a noun with a missing article. Does it sound like a call to action?
2. The word order. Maybe moving the verbs closer would make it better?

> Network and connect for passenger route development!

I know that "network" can be a verb. I know the first sentence is grammatically correct. I am asking how the sentence reads to a native speaker. Because I, as a native Russian, feel that it reads as a noun-phrase, not as a verb-phrase, which has been confirmed by one of those who took the time to answer (thank you!).

Comment: Are you writing this, or are you wondering how to parse someone else's statement?

Comment: I've been asked to evaluate if this would be a good slogan.

Comment: Maybe you want something like "Network with passenger route development experts" or "Networking for the passenger route development community".

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("no research / ELL"). Hi Inna, did you consult a dictionary before you asked here? The first two dictionaries I found online defined *network* as a verb, with examples. Our [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "Be sure to [mention the research you've done](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5043) and what you're still hoping to learn!" For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: *Network and connect with others about passenger route development!*

Comment: To make explicit what was implied in Mr. Bradford's comment, what is problematic in this example is not the use of *network* as a verb, but the choice of *for* as the preposition to go with it.

Answer (score 2):

The first example is unclear. Not being a route development professional (or even previously aware that such a career existed), I read *network for passenger route development* as a noun phrase, a network whose purpose is to develop passenger routes.

The second example makes it more clear that *network* is meant as a verb, but still sounds as if the purpose of the networking and connecting is to develop passenger routes, rather than just to discuss the topic of passenger route development.

Answer (score -2):

Is **to network** perceived as a verb?

Yes, the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/126343?rskey=Qc0dIq&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) lists 4 senses of the verb.  Here is one of those:

> intransitive orig. U.S. To engage in social or professional
>   ‘networking’

As in:

> 1988   Times 25 Mar.    She wanted publicity for her charity and
>   seized the opportunity to network.

And in your

> ```
> Network for passenger route development and connect!
> ```

in context you mentioned it should be apparent and understood.  Otherwise I would say"

```
Network (with others) for passenger route development and connect!
```

Comment: I think OP knows that *network* can be used as a verb. They're asking if it will be understood as a verb in their given example.